# How do you move text down a line in Assembly programming language?

Tags: assembly, mips

I can't figure out how to print these two questions on separate lines. Any help is appreciated! So far this is what i have and it prints all on one line.

```
.data

my_string: .asciiz "What is your course score? 0-100"
my_string2: .asciiz "What is the curve value? 2-8"

    .text
    .globl main


 main:

    li $v0, 4
    la $a0, my_string
    syscall

    li $v1, 4
    la $a1, my_string2
    syscall

    jr$31               #Return from main (stop program)
```

Answer (score 4):

You probably want to use a newline at the end of your strings, e.g.

```
my_string: .asciiz "What is your course score? 0-100\n"
```

I'm not exactly sure how your syscall works, but this should insert a line break in many contexts. `\n` is an escape sequence to input the usually invisible (and platform-dependent) [newline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) character.

Comment: @MariaS: you should click the check-box under the vote arrows, then.  @ hcs:  GNU as (aka gas) syntax does support [C-style backslash escapes in strings](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Strings.html).  But maybe this is a variant of gas syntax, because the usual directive for zero-terminated strings is `.asciz` (one i).  Maria: you should tag your question with what kind of assembly language.  It looks like MIPS to me, but IDK what environment (e.g. SPIM, MARS, or whatever else.)  It would be good to add a tag to your question, although of course the solution didn't depend on it.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I expect it's MARS or SPIM

Comment: Yeah same, but like you I have no idea which :P  I don't even know if they use the same system call API or ABI.  I know it's not much like the POSIX API, since there are system calls to print integers in decimal.